# Getting Unknown error In IE8

Tags: javascript

In IE8 I am facing an issue while calling a method through an object.

The following is the code snippet

**gen.js**

```
function getmystring()
{

}

function DispString()
{
   var  = this.getmystring(); // while executing this line, we are getting Unknown error
   ...
   ...
   ...
}

......
......
......



var mystring_Def = {
global: {
    cur: null
},
//constructor defs
constructor: {
...
...
...
},
//properties defs which contains getmystring & DispString
...
...
...
}
};
```

my html contains the following code snippet

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
...
...
...

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" SRC="gen.js"> </SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
var abc = mystring_Def.global.cur; // mystring_Def.global.cur is intialized before calling this page
document.writeln(DispString());

...
...
...
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

`mystring_Def` is initialized in some other script.

I am getting "Unknown exception" when calling  `this.getmystring()`.

If call the method `getmystring()` in an html page, it is working fine, but I am getting error when i am calling in `DispString()`.

I checked whether this is constructed or not using `typeof`, and itt is showing as function. Using `this` i can access other properties except function objects.

The above code is working fine in IE6 and IE7, but failing in IE8.

It would be gratefyl if anyone give some pointers to solve the above problem.

Comment: I'm confused; what is it that you expect the `this` variable to reference in that function?  I suspect that's the root of the problem, or at least a significant factor.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could post a repro link or an http://sscce.org/.

Comment: 1. Removing all the code makes it pretty hard to debug. 2. Name that variable in DispString. 3. Don't put curly braces on a new line like that.

Comment: Sorry while posting the code, i committed that mistake ie extra curly braces and unknown variable name. But the error is same

Answer (score 0):

try passing this as a parameter too.  this will create reference to current object.Problem which I think is ,this doesn't reference to anything while this.getmystring() is called.